# Is there a way to get to lower granularity converting from scientific notation

Tags: sql-server, scientific-notation

Initially I am receiving a value such as 61290983520229040997, and I subsequently am receiving a file with this in scientific notation in the form of 6.1291E+19.  Is it possible to convert this back to this granularity as my attempts casting always end up with a value of 61291000000000000000.  Based on my understanding this conversion makes sense, but I am hoping there is a way to get back to the original granularity.

Using Data Conversion Transformation to decimal[DT_DECIMAL] I get the value of 61291000000000000000

Comment: 61291000000000000000 = 6.1291E+19, 61291000000000000001 = 6.1291E+19 etc

Comment: You want "greater precision" not "lower granularity".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to convert this back to this granularity

No.

If you have a file that has the literal text `6.1291E+19`, how would you expect SQL Server to derive any additional information or numbers after 6.1291?

Comment: Thank you this confirmed my understanding, but I wanted to make sure that I was not overlooking anything.